# Company with a volume vs Company with volume

Tags: articles, idioms, quantifiers

I would like to say a company is sizable.

Which expression is correct between a company with a volume and a company with volume?

P.S.

Is the sentence "a company is sizable" also grammatically acceptable?

Comment: 'A company with (a) volume' does not sound idiomatic or natural to me, a native speaker of American English. Is there a reason you do not want to say 'a sizeable company'?

Comment: We do use the expression [*a sizeable company*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+sizeable+company%22) (864 hits in Google Books), but despite 13 hits for [*a voluminous company*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+voluminous+company%22) I don't find that remotely acceptable (except in contexts like *a voluminous **company policy book***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wow, thanks for your research! Where did you get the outcome from? Did you just type in the words with quotation marks at Google Books? Is there a way to find word usage statistics at different times?

Comment: You can set date ranges in Google Books. Or use [NGrams like this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=voluminous+hair&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvoluminous%20hair%3B%2Cc0) to see how ***voluminous hair***, for example, has become much more common over recent decades (on account of everyone wants it, and shampoo manufacturers are always trying to flog it, I dunno).

Comment: btw - you'll sometimes hear that someone has [***big hair***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/big-hair), but I never heard of anyone having ***sizeable hair!***

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for useful information. I will definitely enjoy NGrams!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression

> a company with volume

might be understood to possibly mean a "loud" company.  "Volume" itself is not usually used to measure the "size" of a company.  However, it can be used to measure the "throughput" of a company

> The business model for grocery stores is to have razor thin margins but very high *volume*.

It would be best to directly say

> The company is sizeable.
>   It is a sizeable company.

to mean "it is a large company".

Comment: I know this has to do with different grammatical rule but is the sentence "a company is sizable" also grammatically acceptable? When we say a company, doesn't that signify companies at general not a specific one? Since the word company itself does not have connotation of it being a large company, isn't "a company is sizable" wrong?

Comment: "A company is sizeable" is understandable and correct, but the usual phrasing would be "It is a sizeable company" which literally means "it is a big company".

Answer (score 3):

The word volume means a quantity or amount.

A company with (a) volume = A company with (a) quantity or (an) amount. So the sentence is unidiomatic and meaningless.

As for the sentence A company is sizeable, it's correct grammatically - sizeable means fairly large. Here, you are talking about companies in general; it means all companies are fairly large.

If you are referring to a specific company, you should use "the" with company as follows:

The company is sizeable.

The company has a large/sizeable volume of business.